# android studio search does not find the ones there

Tags: search, android-studio-2.1

having Android Studio v 2.1.3,

When do search, in my project like searching for "per Shiv" it find only one, but for "per Shi" it returns all eight occurrences (they are actually same copy of "// per Shiv J" in different files.
In the search option, I don't have any checkbox checked, and with "anywhere" in the Context box.

Does anyone running into same problem, or if there is some settings I might missed?

Answer (score 1):

after in file/invalidate cache restart, the same search returns right results. not sure why the cache would mess up the search though.